# If $X$ is not Hausdorff, then does $X$ have a compact subset that is not closed?

Tags: general-topology

This is something of a converse to the theorem which says if $X$ is Hausdorff and $C$ is a compact subset of $X$, then $C$ is closed in $X$.  But I do not know if true or not.

Question: If $X$ is T$_1$ but not Hausdorff, then does $X$ necessarily have a compact subset that is not closed?

Comment: no edit needed ;)

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955382/spaces-where-all-compact-subsets-are-closed

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 ooh thank you.  

in my head I was sort of thinking that $X$ is T$_1$.  If single points are not closed then the space is not very interesting to me.

Comment: @ForeverMozart, then add that condition to the body of the question.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328725